# JavaScript/jQuery click function not firing in AJAX call to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a practice exercise working with API (the github one in this case) to get re-used to working with JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX in this way again... and doing things with the returned JSON that are (potentially) cool.

I'm working in a repl at repl.it -- not sure if it's kosher to put the url for that here (I'm still kind of new here), but in case it is:  https://repl.it/@stormy9/SecondWelloffBugs

That way you can run it and see what I'm getting (and not).

In the first AJAX call, I'm pulling in the user information fine, and picking out just the data I want to display and displaying it.

In the second AJAX call, my loop is pulling in the whole list of repos, and I'm picking out and showing just the data I asked for as I asked for it.

So all of that is working as I thought it would.

But... I want to -- when a button is clicked -- show a list of commits for the repo who's button was clicked.  The idea being, to append it, in similar fashion to how I appended the list of repos -- by looping through the JSON that is returned and pulling out what I want to display.

This last bit is what is not working -- nothing happens when you click, except the console tab in the repl gets a red 'x', but no error message.  The click event is not firing for some reason I can't figure out.

I have the url formed correctly, to get the list of commits -- because I can produce a link for each repo that when clicked opens up a new tab of the appropriate API results.

here is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>stormy</title>
        <link href="mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------->
    <body>
        <h3> my github repo list </h3>
        <hr>

        <div id="error_msg"></div>

        <div id="card">
            <div id="one"></div>
            <div id="two"></div>
            <div id="three"></div>
            <div id="four"></div>
            <div id="five"></div>
            <div id="repo_list_spot"></div>
        </div> <!-- end of 'card' div -->

        <hr>
        <div id="six"></div>
        <div id="seven"></div>

        <!----------------------------------------------------->
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>

    </body>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------->
</html>
```

and here is the JavaScript etc.:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // vars for the entire `document.ready` function
    var baseURL = "https://api.github.com/";
    var per_page = "?per_page=100";      // else you just get 1st 30 repos
    var userName = "stormy9";

    var get_user_json;
    var get_repo_list_json;

    //=======================================================================
    // GET USER INFO/DETAILS
    //    this is the call to get a list of all repos for a user:
    //       https://api.github.com/users/Stormy9
    //          this returns a JSON object -- pull properties outta there
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "users/"+userName,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        success: function(get_user_info) {
            // assign this response to our variable declared up-top..... 
            //    so => save the whole json response here locally
            get_user_json = get_user_info;

            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            var user_name = get_user_info.name;
            var user_email = get_user_info.email;
            var public_repos = get_user_info.public_repos;
            var bio = get_user_info.bio;
            var location = get_user_info.location;

            $('#one').html("<b>user name = </b>" + user_name);
            $('#two').html("<b>email = </b>" + user_email);
            $('#three').html("<b># of public repos = </b>" + public_repos);
            $('#four').html("<b>user bio = </b>" + bio);
            $('#five').html("<b>user location = </b>" + location);

        }, // end of GET USER SUCCESS function 
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        error: function(xhr){
            $("#error_msg").text("error getting user details..... " + 
                                    xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

        }, // end of GET USER ERROR function
    }); // end of GET USER AJAX function (like the whole thing)
    //=========================================================================
    // GET ALL REPOS FOR A GIVEN USER -- then loop thru them 
    //    this is the call to get a list of all repos for a user:
    //       https://api.github.com/users/stormy9/repos
    //          this returns an array of JSON objects
    //
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "users/"+userName+"/repos"+per_page,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        success: function(get_users_repo_list) {
            // assign response to our variable declared up-top..... 
            //    so => save the whole json response here locally
            get_repo_list_json = get_users_repo_list;

            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            for (var i = 0; i <  get_repo_list_json.length; i++)
            {
                var ordinal = i+1;
                var repo_name =  get_repo_list_json[i].name;    // aka 'CS407'
                var repo_url =  get_repo_list_json[i].html_url;
                var owner =  get_repo_list_json[i].owner.login;  // aka Stormy9
                var updated =  get_repo_list_json[i].updated_at;
                var repo_av =  get_repo_list_json[i].owner.avatar_url;

                var list_commits_url = baseURL + "repos/" + userName + "/" + repo_name + "/commits"

                // still in our for-loop.....
                $("#repo_list_spot").append("<div class='repo_box'>" + ordinal +
                    "<div class='repo_name'><a href='" + repo_url +
                    "' target='_blank'>" + repo_name + "</a></div>" + 
                    "<div>" + owner + "</div>" + 
                    "<div><img src='" + repo_av + 
                    "' width='72px' height='72px'></div>" +
                    "<button type='button' id='list_commits_button'>list commits</button>" + 
                    "<div><a href='" + list_commits_url + "' target='blank'> list commits</a></div>" +
                    "</div>");
            } // end of the for-loop for listing the user's repos.....
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            // GET LIST OF COMMITS FOR SPECIFIC REPO BUTTON CLICKED
            //    this is the call to get a list of all repos for a user:
            //       https://api.github.com/repos/Stormy9/name_of_repo/commits
            //          this returns an array of JSON objects
            //
            $('#list_commits_button').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: list_commits_url,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //--------------------------------------------------------
                    success: function(get_commits_list_for_a_repo) {
                        // assign response to a local variable..... 
                        //    so => save the whole json response here locally
                        var commit_list_json = get_commits_list_for_a_repo;

                        var stringified_commit_list = JSON.stringify(get_commits_list_for_a_repo, null, 5);

                        //console.log(get_commits_list_for_a_repo);
                        console.log(stringified_commit_list);

                        //---------------------------------------------------
                        // neither of these work.....
                        //$('#six').html(get_commits_list_for_a_repo)

                        $('#six').html(stringified_commit_list);

                    }, // end of GET COMMIT LIST FOR A REPO SUCCESS function

                    error: function(xhr) {
                        $("#error_msg").text("error getting commits..... " + 
                                            xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

                    }, // end of GET COMMIT LIST FOR A REPO ERROR function
                }); // end of LIST COMMITS ON A REPO ajax function 
            }); // end of jQuery CLICK function
            //----------------------------------------------------------
        }, // end of GET REPO LIST SUCCESS function 
        error: function(xhr){
            $("#error_msg").text("error getting repo list..... " + 
                                    xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

        }, // end of GET USER ERROR function
    }); // end of GET REPO LIST AJAX function
    //==================================================================
    }); // end of entire jQuery DOCUMENT READY function
```

Here is what I *am* getting (well, in part, there are 41 repos, but you get the idea):

[image: correctly listing repos asked for]

and when you click on "list commits" text link a new tab opens, with the correct/expected API result..... so the uri I constructed is correct.

but clicking the "list commits" **button** doesn't do anything -- I just get a red 'x' on the console tab of my repl, like so:
[image]
with no error message/feedback.

I've tried having my click function in various places -- I thought putting it right after where the button is created -- inside that `success` function -- would be best?

I have looked at the suggested/similar questions/answers on here, but none of them seem to fit..... and I'm not even sure what to Google, to find possible solutions.

Can anyone explain to me why my click function is not firing, and show me a solution that I'm apparently not thinking of?

**EDIT:**

I fixed the quotes around "GET" on line 94 (and can't believe I left those off in the first place).

However, the click event still does nothing when you click the button -- I just don't get a red 'x' on my console anymore.  [=

Comment: Did you not look at the console? `Uncaught ReferenceError: GET is not defined`

Comment: I did,  but the console just showed me a blank screen.   =[

If I had gotten a message like that, I might have figured something out.   [=

Comment: Your demo link has that error message on it. It has a console tab.

Comment: I'm really not trying to be obtuse, but I know there's a console tab -- before I was returning things to the html, I was returning them with `console.log`..... but when I click on it, it does not say that -- it's just blank/black.  Which is kinda weird that it shows that to you and not me!

Comment: The image https://i.stack.imgur.com/pizk1.png you posted shows their console and the red mark is saying there was an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the follow changes to myscript.js:

In line 91 you should change this:

```
$('#list_commits_button').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#list_commits_button').on('click', function(){
```

Because you are creating the button "#list_commits_button" after the page has been loaded. Doc: https://api.jquery.com/on/

And in line 94 be GET with quotes like this:

```
type: "GET"
```

Comment: I can't believe I did that.....

In any event, fixing that does not make the click event fire.

Comment: Your "from" and "to" are the same..... but checking out the link you sent, would you suggest: `$('#repo_list_spot').on('click', '#list_commits_button', function() {`

Comment: I made the change I indicated above -- it worked!  Thank you so much for sending me that page about the jQuery `on()` function.